# AWS Data Pipeline - Java SDK - How to put a pipeline definition from JSON file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline, aws-java-sdk

I have an AWS data pipeline definition in JSON format

Using Java SDK I have created an empty pipeline and now I would like to use my JSON to put the pipeline definition. 
Basically I would like to create a PutPipelineDefinitionRequest (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/datapipeline/model/PutPipelineDefinitionRequest.html) without creating the PipelineObjects one by one.

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to upload the JSON as the pipeline definition. You can however iterate over the JSON and create the array of pipeline objects.

Comment: Ok. Finally as you said I have created the PipelineObjects iterating over the Json again. Even if I hope they will implement this functionality soon, in the meanwhile if somebody needs it, I followed the code in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582478/put-json-data-pipeline-definition-using-boto3?rq=1